# How could I find the location of a running process using Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, process, psutil

I need to find the location of the web-browser in the program I'm making.

I've decided to do this by running a browser window then finding the path of it. I've looked at psutil but still can't figure out how to do it.

I'm doing this cause I can't seem to open a new window using the webbrowser library, it opens in a new tab regardless of wherever I tell it to or not. So I plan to use the commands explained here: http://kb.mozillazine.org/Command_line_arguments#List_of_command_line_arguments_.28incomplete.29

I'm using Python 3.8.6 on Windows 10

Answer (score 2):

Found a solution using psutil finally!

```
import psutil

def findPath(name):
    for pid in psutil.pids():
        if psutil.Process(pid).name() == name:
            return psutil.Process(pid).exe()

print(findPath('firefox.exe'))
```

This loops through all pids and checks to see if the pids name is the same as the name variable passed to the findPath function.

Comment: What if many processes have same name but different location?

Answer (score 1):

[Link to original code (psutil)](https://psutil.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#find-process-by-name)

I modified original code to meet your needs. Unfortunately I cannot test them since I am on **Android** platform and <kbd>psutil</kbd> module in **Termux**'s *Python* can't access (since Android update) stats due security/privacy reasons so if they don't work please tell me

> Simple approach

```py
import psutil

def findPath(name: str) -> list:
    ls: list = [] # since many processes can have same name it's better to make list of them
    for p in psutil.process_iter(['name', 'pid']):
        if p.info['name'] == name:
            ls.append(psutil.Process(p.info['pid']).exe())
    return ls
```

> More advanced

```py
import os
import psutil

def findPathAdvanced(name: str) -> list:
    ls: list = [] # same reason as previous code
    for p in psutil.process_iter(["name", "exe", "cmdline", "pid"]):
        if name == p.info['name'] or p.info['exe'] and os.path.basename(p.info['exe']) == name or p.info['cmdline'] and p.info['cmdline'][0] == name:
            ls.append(psutil.Process(p.info['pid']).exe())
    return ls
```

Comment: p.cmdline()==['python', '-c', "import os;os.system('pause')"];p.exe()=='C:\\QGB\\miniforge3\\python.exe'